# How to query multiple columns when using a python udf in hive?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, udf

I am trying to execute this query:

```
add FILE /home/user1/test/test_udf.py;

SELECT a.hash_code, col2
FROM (SELECT transform (col2, col3) using 'python test_udf.py' as hash_code, col2
      FROM sample_table) a ;
```

I am able to successfully generate the hash_code using the udf but the other column (col2) is getting populated as `NULL`.

**Sample Output**:

```
sjhfshhalksjlkfj128798172jasjhas   NULL
ajsdlkja982988290819189089089889   NULL
jhsad817982mnsandkjsahj982398290   NULL
```

Comment: SELECT a.hash_code, a.col2 from (select transform (col2,col3) using 'python test_udf.py' as hash_code, col2 from sample_table) a ; also giving the same result

Comment: Is the true value is `NULL`?

Comment: No, I have valid value in the column "col2"

Comment: try `SELECT a.hash_code, a.col2 from (select col2, transform (col2,col3) using 'python test_udf.py' as hash_codefrom sample_table) a`?

Comment: with the above query my query is failing with "cannot recognize input near 'transform' '(' 'package_id' in select expression.  I am pasting my original query here for your refeence.  SELECT a.hash_code,a.package_id from (select package_id, transform (package_id,file_name,system) using 'python md5hash_conv_udf.py'  as hash_code from 
raw_pharm_pbm.audit_table) a ;

Comment: what is the data type of 'col2' in the 'a' table?

Comment: col2 is of type bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what's wrong with your HiveSql.

In `transform (col2, col3) using 'python test_udf.py' as hash_code, col2 FROM sample_table`, the `hash_code, col2`'s value is parsed from `transform (col2, col3)`'s return value.

The `clo2` is parsed from `transform (col2, col3)`, which is `NULL`.

I read the [Transform doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform), picked up the related info  as below.

**Transform/Map-Reduce Syntax**

```
SELECT TRANSFORM '(' expression (',' expression)* ')'
  (inRowFormat)?
  USING 'my_reduce_script'
  ( AS colName (',' colName)* )?
  (outRowFormat)? (outRecordReader)?
```

You'd better not mix `transform` with other `select`, as the syntax won't support.

**Update：**

There is a hack to do what you want: let the  `test_udf.py` return `hash_code\t col2`.
So you can parse `hash_code, col2` from it. This would solve your problem.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate method to select more than one column and for one of the column i have to use python udf.  Like "select transform(col1) using 'python udf.py' as msg, col2 from table;"

Comment: Looks like its the only solution available. When i use java udf i dont have these issues. I want  this udf should be generic. If i have to use this on a different table with different number of columns it will be challenge.